# Why Megaraid-sas and mdadm Raid 1+0 = Raid 10 Slow actual read speeds?

Tags: mdadm, raid10, megaraid

One of raid cards were giving multibit ecc ram module failure , thats why I am moving 60TB of data from one server to another ...

Getting 60-100 Mb/s read speeds 3 Megaraid sas raid1 s 8+8+6 x 10TB Disks and spanning them with raid 0 using mdadm when compresisng a folder with tar pigz to another network raid5 folder or same server. I rarely beat 100mb/s for a couple of seconds in an hour (up to 250mb/s) ...

However When I copy a huge file 8 GB it copies with 10G Ethernet 987mb/s. Also `hdparm -tT /dev/md0p1` gives 1.5 GB/s.

Cluster size of disks and raid array all 4096 k %75 of files are >30mb there GB files too
How can I tar.gz reliably and as fast as possible ...
What is wrong with this machine

One of raid cards were giving multibit ecc ram module failure so can it be the culprit behind slow speeds and or is it because disks are mechanical however keep in mind file distribution is like this :

```
Bytes           Number of Files:        
            0  14
            16  24
            32  21
            64 603
           128 207
           256 1677
           512 2361
          1024  45
          2048  90
          4096 112
          8192 358
         16384 315
         32768 235
         65536 309
        131072 296
        262144 2275
        524288 1148
       1048576 2187
       2097152 3204
       4194304 2708
       8388608 2148
      16777216 703
      33554432 1585
      67108864 906
     134217728 259
     268435456  71
     536870912  42
    1073741824  33
    2147483648  38
    4294967296  16
```

Here is a little bit human readable version :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15J3LsU5G_km70mW0yE6ehiK4oHZmOLuUxRpBCM25-r0/edit?usp=sharing

Any practical workaround to copy all data before I change faulty raid card ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that , small files especially close to cluster size of raid is a hell to copy using mechanical disks and it can go way down ... less than 250Kb/sec while copying small files.

Two workarounds are enabling raid card cache which is 512mb and plentiful for streaming small files when it has a chance ... Better, we can use nvme or sata-ssd disk as a cache using bcache in linux and it leads to 256 MB/sec to 1GB/sec speeds when copying files with file size 512KB to 1MB. Bcache can be adjusted using sysfs. There is a sequantial_cutoff parameter when you set it to 1MB smaller than 1MB files go to the sata-sdd or nvme cache and others write normally. Default sequantial_cutoff is 4MB.

And it turns out we have unplugged server case fans because of incredible noise. And forgot them to re-plug that was heating raid card and makes it give single-multibit ECC errors. ! Especially the card in the middle of other two raid cards gave error. I guess it is because they have passive cooling and the one in the middle heats most. Nevertheless slow copy speed was nothing to do with it.

The final answer is: There is nothing wrong with very slow speeds with mechanical disk raid setups when copying files near to cluster size or files smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

You even didn't mention FS nor if it has been tuned for RAID layout. Yes, it could be. Secondly, there's no surprise that small files are likely to be scattered across the disk meanwhile huge ones typically have its regions continuous. Rotational storage has hard time with that state of things.